# Switched from mobile application testing to Browser testing

Tags: manual-testing, browsers, web

As i have switched from mobile application testing to Browser testing.Can i know what are the major things to cover up during web testing.Is there any major differences in test between them?Is automation only tool to test web testing?If no can i know the steps for testing web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website Testing on Browser you must see or perform below checkpoint:

1. UI Appearance: Placements, Fonts, Color combination, Spell Checks,
2. Functionality of All Web elements -- same as that of Mobile Testing
3. Appearance of Dialog Box on some actions
4. Behavior for Right click, Drag, and Drop
5. Browser Back and Forward button
6. In Security Purpose: Check the URL's when navigating or when login into the application. The URL should not have any sought of password in them
7. Appearances of Drop Downs and Lists
8. Uploading of files
9. Compatibility Testing with different versions of the browser
10. Multi-Browser Testing

Performance Testing, Security Testing, Functional and Database Testing should be done for both Mobile based Websites and Browser Based Websites.

Answer (score 1):

Web application need to be tested in manual as well as in automation.

Before going into automation part, you have to familiarize with the manual testing to understand about the web components.
Then it will be easier for you to work on automation.

You can get an initial insight from this link:
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/web-application-testing/

Answer (score 0):

As you have done mobile testing you will be familiar with functionality and usability testing. In addition,you need to specifically consider -
1.Compatibility testing
2.Database Testing
3.Security Testing And 
4.Performance Testing

This are the steps . Automation test will help you to check basic functionality .But you have to know and cover the website by manual testing.